# How do you switch between files when using prelude's projectile?

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-prelude

Imagine you have these files in your project:

```
a/b/first.png
a/first.png
```

If I trigger projectile with `C-c p f` and write first.png, and I write first.png , it will show me both files. Is there a way to select the next file?

Example: [image]

In the image below, the first file in the list is .document. Without writing any other letter, is it possible to switch through the list provided by projectile? Is there a combination that will cycle through those file names, like , press some key combination and then .gitignore is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, the projectile uses the [ido package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) for file name completions, and other things. The ido (and many other packages) uses the `C-s` to switch to next file name, and `C-r` to switch to previous file. See "Using IDO" section in previous link

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard arrow keys will toggle through options as well, and you can then hit enter when the file you want is highlighted next to the text you typed.